# Visual C++: why watch view for derived class is not showing fields of base class?

Tags: visual-c++

I have split some class MyClass to 2 classes
MyClassBase and MyClassDerived
for example see the attached images:

## MyClassDerived

I am seeing only the members MyClassDerived, no details on other base class members
http://i46.tinypic.com/14ljwxs.jpg

I need to expand to see more members of the class

## MyClass

I see much more members of the class without expanding
http://i45.tinypic.com/mwfbzt.jpg

why doesnt the watch shows more members, is there any option to cause the watch to show more members??

Comment: Have you tried casting the watch variable `(MyClass)source` or checked that RTTI is enabled in your compiler settings?

Comment: I dont have MyClass any more, I have split it into MyClassBase & MyClassDerived, but now I see only the single member of MyClassDerived which is gpp and dont see members of the base class even though there is space for them